# how do I return a float starting at a certain index in a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String that has data such as:

```
String data = "Some information and then value1=17561.2 and then value2=15672.2"
```

How do I return 17561.2 most efficiently in Java?

```
String queryString = "value1";

while data.charAt(outputStr.indexOf(queryString)+queryString.length()) is a number

    -save it to an array
    which you later convert to a String

elihw
```

This seems kind-of convoluted.

Would regexs be perfect here?  How would I craft a regular expression to do this?

Comment: Should the regex fail on integers, or should it find those, too?

Comment: It should find all valid numbers, integers included, but I think the data will usually have fractional components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a decimal number (or an int) in a string, you could use the regular expression

```
[+-]?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+)
```

This will not find floats in exponential notation, though (1.2E15 or some such).

**Explanation:**

```
[+-]?     # optional sign
(?:       # either
 \d*\.\d+ # float with optional integer part
 |        # or
 \d+      # just integer
)
```

In Java (to iterate over all matches in a string):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[+-]?(?:\\d*\\.\\d+|\\d+)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
    // match start: regexMatcher.start()
    // match end: regexMatcher.end()
}
```